# Facebook Header

Tags: php, facebook

I'm just curious about facebook. These are my question.

1. How does the facebook header in its page doesn't reloads while its content and body does?
2. Is there any other programming or scripting language used aside from php, javascript and ajax in making facebook page?

Thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly how Facebook implements this but my guess is that use some kind of pushState and AJAX for only updating parts of the site(HTML).

**PushState** is used for the browisng history and makes the webpage work and behave exactly like it would with a full page reload. It changes the address in the browser's address bar and enables the user to use the back and forward buttons in the browser just like ordinary page loads. The user will not be able to tell the difference.

**AJAX** is used to to fetch the new content in the background and then update the DOM/HTML without a reload of the page just like ordinary AJAX calls. You can have div with the page specific content that are updated when you use the navigation without loading the header and footer.

**Example:**

A click on the navigation links will only reload the contents off the #content div with an AJAX call in the background.

```
 <html>
      <head></head>
      <body>
           <header>
                <nav>
                      <a href="/page1">Page 1</a>
                      <a href="/page2">Page 2</a>
                </nav>
           </header>
           <div id="content">
              page content
           </div>
           <footer>
              footer content
           </footer>
       </body>
<html>
```

This could be done pretty easily with the jQuery plugin **[PJAX](http://pjax.heroku.com/)** for example. See the [GitHub page](https://github.com/defunkt/jquery-pjax) for more details about implementation and downloads

Note: This does not work in IE 9(but it should work in IE 10 but I haven't tried nor confirmed this myself) and down, but most tools for this, including PJAX, makes it easy to degrade gracefully so unsupported browsers get a full page reload.